# resize many div of same class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to force the width of different Div elements using the same class in a loop.

But all the Div elements maintain the same size of the last element in the loop.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    resizeSides()
  });

  function resizeSides() {
    var title_width = $(".title-onglet").width();
    var totale_width = $(".titre-onglet").width();
    var new_width = totale_width - title_width;
    var sides_width = new_width;
    $(".ligne-onglet-pale").css("width",sides_width);
  } 
</script>
```

I'm just missing something... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML, please?

Comment: <div class="titre-onglet">
                                                        
<div class="ligne-onglet-pale ligne-gauche"></div>
                                                        
<p class="title-onglet"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                                         
<div class="ligne-onglet-pale ligne-droit"></div>
                                                         
<div style="clear:both;"></div>  
                                                         
</div>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".ligne-onglet-pale").css("width",sides_width + 'px');
```

instead of this:

```
$(".ligne-onglet-pale").css("width",sides_width);
```

If it doesn't work check if you have some error in console, try to make a `console.log(sides_width);` to see if is the right value.
if it doesn't work again without error check if you have select the right element by class

Comment: Its like if it keep in memory le last one

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle please? @user3271655

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of beginner and I dont really know  what jsfiddle is !

Comment: jsfiddle.org you can put your html and your jquery to simulate your problem @user3271655

Comment: is a little bit difficult to see but the green box is your div with your width calculated, yellow div is 100. if you see the width caluclate is 50 it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/3wzAq/3/ @user3271655

Comment: Yes I know its work if you set the width of the yellow box. The thing is that the width of this box will never be the same, so it as to be dynamic.